# R - Convert Column one into Row-names

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I'm trying to do a correlation-matrix and for this the values (Faculty) in the first column should be converted into the row names.

This is how the data looks:

```
   Row     Faculty                                  Answer Q1   
    1      Architecture, Building and Planning      5    
    2      Social studies                           20 
    3      Law                                      2
    4      Business and Administrative studies.     45
    5      Languages                                53
    6      Historical and Philosophical studies.    16
    7      Creative Arts and Design                 9
```

This is what I would like:

```
 Row                                      Answer Q1   
 Architecture, Building and Planning      5    
 Social studies                           20 
 Law                                      2
 Business and Administrative studies.     45
 Languages                                53
 Historical and Philosophical studies.    16
 Creative Arts and Design                 9
```

I tried `rownames(mydata) <- mydata[, 1]`

which gives me the error:

```
`(`*tmp*`, value = list(Subject = c("(1) Architecture, Building and Planning",  : 
      length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Please show the dput of the example

Comment: try using `mydata[[1]]` because when extracting just one column it might be returning a data.frame. or else use `drop = TRUE`

Comment: I just tried this, still an error: `error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
In addition: Warning message:
Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.`

Comment: @akrun :  that's the put if that helps `structure(list(Subject = c("(1) Medicine and Dentistry", "(2) Subjects allied to Medicine", 
"(3) Biological Sciences", "(6) Physical Sciences", "(7) Mathematical Sciences", 
"(8) Computer Science", "(9) Engineering and Technology", "(A) Architecture, Building and Planning", 
"(B) Social studies", "(C) Law", "(D) Business and Administrative studies", 
"(F) Languages", "(G) Historical and Philosophical studies", 
"(H) Creative Arts and Design", "(I) Education", "(I)Other Education", 
"(L) Geographical Studies")`

Comment: So, basically, it shows a `list` with strings  `mydata
$Subject
 [1] "(1) Medicine and Dentistry"`

Comment: yes, the example above is just an excerpt

Comment: if you are using a tibble, look at:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.0/topics/rownames?

Comment: thank you @Wietze314, I'll have a look